# Как получить сообщение всем потокам?

Tags: c++, linux, c

Например я получаю из очереди сообщение и хочу его разослать всем потокам. Я думал про общую память, но вроде вдруг не все потоки успеют использовать сообщение из общей памяти. А если использовать очередь, то только один поток получает сообщение.

Как быть? Может я чего то не знаю, неужели невозможно отправить типа broadcast какого нибудь.

Для чего это мне нужно. Я пока рассматриваю так. У моей программы есть unix socket, если к нему подключается клиент, то создаётся отдельный поток, и вот для этого мне и нужно рассылать всем потокам сообщение, чтобы поток мог клиенту отправить в unix сокет сообщение.

Или лучше не так делать?

Answer (score 2):

> А если использовать очередь, то только один поток получает сообщение.

Но это можно победить. Наверное, вы знаете, что в Linux поддержвается два типа очередей сообщений. Для конкретности, давайте будем говорить о очередях System V. Там предполагается, что сообщение имеет тип такой структуры:

```
/* message buffer for msgsnd and msgrcv calls */
struct msgbuf {
        long mtype;         /* type of message */
        char mtext[1];      /* message text */
};
```

Обратите внимание на поле mtype. Если к очереди "прицеплено" несколько абонентов, то это поле можно использовать в качестве адреса получателя. Т.е. каждый процесс знает свой адрес (например - pid), а отправитель этот адрес указывает в сообщении.

Тогда получатель, используя вызов

```
msgrcv(msqid, msgp, msgsz, mtype, msgflg); // mtip - мой адрес
```

получит только сообщения, адресованные конкретно ему. Легко придумать "широковещательный" адрес в очереди сообщений. Например -1.

Однако возникает проблема - после того, как первый попавшийся клиент забрал это "широковещательное" сообщение из очереди, остальным оно уже недоступно. Но эта проблема легко решается. Модифицируем структуру сообщений:

```
struct msgbuf {
        long mtype;         /* type of message */
        long num_rec;       /* Количество получателей данного сообщения */
        char mtext[1];      /* message text */
};
```

Для "одноадресного" сообщения в поле *num_rec* пишем единичку. Если же сервер желает отправить "широкополосное" сообщение всем клиентам, то он задаёт в этом поле число присоединившихся клиентов.

Клиент, получив сообщение с "широкополосным" адресом, декрементирует это поле и, если оно всё еще > 0, немедленно помещает его обратно в очередь сообщение.

Вот и весь алгоритм.

Comment: Спасибо. А откуда вы это узнали?

Comment: @xverizex *А откуда вы это узнали?* - ну, сейчас уже трудно вспомнить, но (скорее всего) из *man 2 msgrcv*. Первоисточник :-)